# Jasmine: How to pass test suite function to describe method?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

#### What I am doing:

I am using jasmine to test my javascript functions. My describe function & it functions are in different files.

#### What I want to do:

I am trying to pass parameter to describe function but i am getting an error.

#### My code:

```
describe("Test file-utils funtions",fileUtilsFunc("abc"))
// Getting Error: describe expects a function argument; received [object Undefined]
```

It is not allowing to pass "abc" parameter.

Comment: It seems that `fileUtilsFunc("abc")` does not return a function.

Comment: What happens if you call describe("Test file-utils funtions",fileUtilsFunc) ?

Comment: @VLAZ No, its not like that. My question is can i pass parameter to fileUtilsFunc function, which itself is a parameter for describe.

Comment: @LajosArpad  It will take abc parameter, perform one action on that & then it will match with expected output

Comment: Am I correctly understanding that this is the solution to the problem you have described?

Comment: @Vish you can but not if `fileUtilsFunc` doesn't return a function itself, since `describe` expects a function. You can partially apply `fileUtilsFunc` and pass that or create a new anonymous one that will call `fileUtilsFunc` with the given parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Probable Issue

Describe expects two arguments:

- String with description of test suite
- Function containing test cases (i.e. containing "it" parts)

In your code you are passing the former correctly, but the latter is not a name of a function, but a function call which will be evaluated. Unless your *fileUtilsFunc* function returns another function it won't work. *fileUtilsFunc* returning undefined appears to be a problem with your code.

## Solution

You should try passing function with test cases:

```
describe("Test file-utils funtions",fileUtilsFunc)

function fileUtilsFunc() {
  it("Test case name", function() {/*test case code*/});
}
```

Or function which returns function with test cases:

```
describe("Test file-utils funtions",fileUtilsFunc())

function fileUtilsFunc() {
  return function() {
    it("Test case name", function() {/*test case code*/});
  }
}
```

Notice difference between **fileUtilsFunc** in first example and **fileUtilsFunc()** in second example.

Comment: Thank you M. Twarog. return function from fileUtilsFunc() function working.